# TextBoxFor not displaying default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I'm currently creating a .NET MVC6 (DNX Core) Web Application. At the moment I'm trying to get a Html.TextBoxFor with a default value but nothing is showing up.
This is what I've got:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @Value = Model.UserData.LastName })
```

I'm sure that Model.UserDate.LastName has a value. It is just not showing up in the textbox.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't using `TextBoxFor` and also setting a value redundant?

Comment: Hi. I want the previous value to be shown as this will be used to edit user information. He might not want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Like @Uwe Keim said I shouldnt be using a **Html.TextBoxFor**.
Instead I should be using an **Html.EditorFor**.

This way I have the model with the information and the EditorFor will take care of the rest.

Thank you.

Comment: It makes no difference if you use `TextBoxFor()` or `EditorFor()` (and you never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods). If the property your binding to has a value,  then that value will be displayed in the textbox - that's how model binding works